# In soccer, which player had the longest dribble then a miss goal?

Tags: football, trivia

In soccer, which player had the longest solo dribble, passed the keeper, then missed the goal?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because requests for specific events are off-topic unless they are particularly notable.

Comment: @PhilipKendall do you have a reference for that? notable, not notable, i'm not sure what you mean. also, we have [trivia](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trivia) questions in this similar format, so what makes this different than the other ones? maybe this one is not answerable or reasonably scoped, but the reason you provide "unless they are particularly notable" is subjective.

Answer (score 3):

Probably not the longest of all time but among recent ones I had this in mind:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FrEhVJohFLo